# Initializing servlet in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

For my domain (palibacsi.de) under a Tomcat server I made a servlet that is supposed to run after the user types in some data. But I get an error message

maybe i did somthing wrong in the web.xml file when initializing the servlet?

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>PaliServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>PaliServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>PaliServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/PaliServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

the servlet is in the folder where (I guess) it should be,  /home/palibacs1/appservers/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/webapps/PaliServlet.class

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message do you get? Any stacktrace?

Comment: Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class webapps.PaliServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class webapps.PaliServlet
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)

Comment: That's not sufficient, there is more of it than that. There is a 'caused by' exception further down.

Comment: Ok, one of the problems was seemingly that i got at home Java 1.7 and the server was 1.8. - The sytem administrator fixed everything:  "switched your JDK to 1.8

In conf/server.xml I set Paliba as default application

I created simple /webapps/Paliba/WEB-INF/web.xml where URL is mapped to servlet class"

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the class path of your servlet relative to your source folder in the servlet-class field.

Lets say your PaliServlet class is located inside **Servlets** folder in java folder marked as source folder. Then you need to give :

```
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>PaliServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>Servlets.PaliServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>PaliServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/PaliServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "webapps" folder, which contains the servlet, is the folder where Tomcat is looking for servlets in the first place (if i got it right), so it is not contained in an extra forlder inside webapps, it is directly in the "source folder" webapps.

Comment: I did as you told and amended the path to: webapps.PaliServlet, then I got a different error message: Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class webapps.PaliServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class webapps.PaliServlet
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
etc.

Comment: Can you give the complete error stack trace ?

Comment: now the message is simply : HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.    - You can check it if you visit the website Palibacsi.de and type in 2 random answers.

Comment: Can you give the resource path . i.e folders structure. It seems your path of servlet is still incorrect.

Comment: the main folder is  "/home/palibacs1". This has several folders. Tomcat is in appservers/apache-tomcat-8.0.37. This has a webapps folder, the PaliServlet.class file is there. If there is an html command to print the folder structure on the screen, i can put it on the html site of my domain...

Comment: Try adding your servlet class in /home/palibacs1/. And then give home.palibacs1.PaliServelet as servelt-class

Comment: Ok, I have tried that as you wrote, but i get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet class `PaliServlet` should have in `/home/palibacs1/appservers/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/webapps/{Your_Project_Name}/WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your solution, but I get the same error message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: home.palibacs1.appservers.apache-tomcat-8.0.37.webapps.Paliba.WEB-INF.classes.PaliServlet

Comment: What abt your web.xml servlet-class path?

Comment: it is <servlet-class>home.palibacs1.appservers.apache-tomcat-8.0.37.webapps.Paliba.WEB-INF.classes.PaliServlet</servlet-class>

Comment: make it like this `<servlet-class>PaliSer‌​vlet</servlet-class>` . Hope it works then.

Comment: thanks - no, it still does not find the class, even if I write only "PaliServlet" in the class path as you suggested. - I will try to get someone look at it next week IRL on my computer, and write the solution here, which has to be sg pretty obvious thing which i overlooked.

Comment: ok..can you restart your tomcat server and check again. Make sure configuration is same as i mentioned.

Comment: ok, thanks. Btw. the project's name is Paliba, and now its not indicated in the class path, but even when I put it in the class path it did not find the servlet